# Iterating nested object in JavaScript withoud jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, object

I'm trying to iterate through a nested object.

```
    array=[
  {
    id: 2,
    items: [
      {
        id: 12
      },
      {
        id: 13
      },
      {
        id: 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    items: [
      {
        id: 15
      },
      {
        id: 16
      },
      {
        id: 17
      },
      {
        id: 18
      },
      {
        id: 19
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    items: [
      {
        id: 20
      },
      {
        id: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    items: [
      {
        id: 22
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I need to push all the ID into one array in order that we can see in the code above. Something like this:

```
arrayOfId = [2, 12, 13, 14, 3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 4, 20, 21, 5, 22];
```

I tried to do it by myself and found some examples here, but they are based on jQuery. I use Angular in my project.

Maybe someone knows solution of this issue with plain JS or Angular?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And same old question for you  :), what have you tried and what issues you faced?

Comment: Is the depth specified or not ?

Comment: @dystroy, not. Only these 2 levels of depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's actually very simple.**

1. get the length of the array.
2. loop through the array and push a new array (`ids`) with the current `id` value.
3. get the length of the nested array.
4. loop through that and push the nested ids also in that array.

---

```
var l=array.length,i=0,ids=[];
for(;i<l;i++){
 ids.push(array[i].id);
 var nested=array[i].items,nl=nested.length,j=0;
 for(;j<nl;ids.push(nested[j++].id));
};

console.log(ids);
alert(ids);

//ids=[2,12,13,14,3,15,16,17,18,19,4,20,21,5,22];
```

In this example i show various ways to write the for loop.
Also by **caching** the `length` and other variables like the `nested` array, the **performance is increased**. I also like to mention, that for simple functions like this, where you have to **LOOP** through multidimensional arrays/objects, 
the use of `forEach`,`map`,`filter` or other "new" native javascript functions is discouraged, as there is a heavy performance loss over the standard `while` & `for` loop (1).They are about 3-4 times slower. At the other side, if you know that your multidimensional array is not that big and the clients use modern browsers the `map` solution is the "short code" alternative (2).

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/axaog3n2/1/

1 https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/2

2 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

if you have any questions just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop inside of another for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  arrayOfId.push(array[i].id);
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    arrayOfId.push(array[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Only if it's a two levels tree (question is unclear)

Comment: @dystroy I disagree. He shows the exact data structure in the question.

Comment: Yes, he commented to confirm since my last comment

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map`

```
//This will give a 2d array of ids [[2,3],[2,3]];
var ids = array.map(function(item) {
    return item.items.map(function(obj) {
        return obj.id
    })
});

//Now flatten and merge
var idList = [];
idList = idList.concat.apply(idList , ids);

//Output:
//[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2kmozrr7/

Answer (score 0):

simple for loop

```
var arrayOfId = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    arrayOfId.push(array[i].id);
    if (array[i]['items'] != undefined && array[i].items.length > 0) {
        for(var j = 0; j < array[i].items.length; j++) {
            arrayOfId.push(array[i].items[j].id);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [];
for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    ids.push(array[x].id);
    if (array[x].items) {
        var items = array[x].items;
        for (var y = 0; y < items.length; y++) {
            if (items[y].id) {
                ids.push(items[y].id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any more nested than that, you'll need to use a recursive function to do it sanely.

```
var results = [];
function build(array, results) {
    for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        results.push(results[x].id);
        if (results[x].items) {
            build(results[x].items, results);
        }
    }
}
build(thatObject, results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create array for result
var b = [];
// iterate over the source array
array.forEach(function (outer) {
    // get the id property and push the value to the result array
    b.push(outer.id);
    // iterate over the items
    outer.items.forEach(function (inner) {
        // get the id property of the inner array object and push the value to the result array
        b.push(inner.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: An explanation of what you're doing would be helpful.